# What is the correct way to close an app in ionic 4 using Angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have tried the following lines to close the application:

```
cordova.plugins.ExitApp();
navigator.app.exitApp();
navigator['App'].exitApp();
App.exitApp();
ionic.Platform.exitApp();
```

I tried to put them in a CloseApp() method as well as trying the backbutton event:

```
this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(10, () => {
  console.log('Handler was called!');
  App.exitApp();

});
```

Where I get no errors but App.exitApp() never hits.

There are various different answers. Is my project maybe built wrong? This is the first app I ever developed.

Comment: this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(99999, () => {
navigator['app'].exitApp(); });

Comment: Thank you this worked. I have been looking for solutions everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Mostafa Harb has answered my question. Seems like my priority was not set high enough. And `navigator['App'].exitApp();` must be `navigator['app'].exitApp();`